# How to call an await statement within a Firebase await statement?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a Firebase Cloud Function that relies upon some data about whether or not certain keys exist in the realtime database, but it's not getting properly returned. It keeps either returning `undefined` or `Promise {}`. Here's the function I'm trying to call:

```
async function checkMatchExists(baseUser: string, friend:string){
return await admin.database().ref('pairs/').child(baseUser).once("value", 
snapshot => {
  return snapshot.exists();
 });
}
```

If I try to call the function within my main function like so:

```
const exists = await checkMatchExists(userId, eachUserId)
```

I end up with the error `await expression is only allowed within an async function`. This is because this is all nested within another async Firebase method:

```
await admin.database()
      .ref(`locations/`).orderByChild('uid').once('value', userList =>{
        let sentToUser;
        userList.forEach(function(child){
             /* where all the troubles are happening */
       });
   });
```

So, how do I use an `await` statement on the outside function call without drawing this error? Is there a way to nest two `await` calls? If not, how could I get data from this function in time?

**UPDATE: I still don't know how to properly access result outside of the .then(). I realize await is the way to go here, but again, I can't use an await within another await.**

Thanks for the help everyone. This was definitely due to confusion over the difference between callbacks and the async/await method. Here's what I changed my function to:

```
async function checkMatchExists(baseUser: string, friend:string){
try{
  const snapshot = await 
  admin.database().ref('pairs/').child(baseUser).once("value")
     console.log("Does the snapshot exist?")
     console.log(snapshot.exists())
  return snapshot.exists()
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    return e
   }
  }
```

And here's how I properly call it within the Firebase Cloud Function:

```
const doesExist = checkMatchExists(eachUserId, userId)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .then(result => console.log("result: " + String(result)))
        .catch(() => 'obligatory catch')
```

Comment: I believe you asked this before.  You're still mixing up the use of a promise and a callback in the call to `once()`.  Just use the promise it returns, don't pass a callback.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Which once() are you referring to? If it's the checkMatchExists() function, how should I structure it so that it just creates a promise?

Comment: Not to hijack Doug's answer or to put words in his mouth... but he means don't pass a callback to ANY `.once()` method. The proper use of `.once()` is like:  `admin.database().ref('pairs/').child(baseUser).once("value").then( res => console.log(res); ).catch( err => console.log(err); )`

Comment: I understand. I made said changes. How should I structure my async function calls then to avoid the `await expression is only allowed...` error?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you understand how `await` works.  It will pause the execution of your code until the promise resolves, and it *also* return the value contained in the promise, or throw an exception if the promise was rejected.  That's how you get a hold of the data in the database.  `const snapshot = await ref.once('value')`

Comment: I understood that. I'm just unsure about how to restructure my original Firebase `await` function so I can call checkMatchExists() properly. I might just be confused about callbacks and how that's causing errors in my function.

Comment: try userlist.forEach(async funtion(child){....